# How to declare an array parameter in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9.2

guys. I tried this code:

```
 def trap_check(payroll[][], timelive[][])
 .
 .
 .
 end
```

I was trying to create a function that accepts 2-dimensional array as parameters. I
was having this error:

```
 syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'
    def trap_check(payroll[][], timelive[][])
```

Can somebody pls tell me how to do it the right way??? Pls help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby you don't declare types, so your function would just be:

```
def trap_check(payroll, timelive)
# code
end
```

And you might call it as such

```
trap_check([[1,2,3,4],[5,6]], [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2]])
```

To verify if payroll is infact an array, you can just do:

```
payroll.is_a?(Array) #=> returns true or false
```

Comment: One more question, how am I gonna access the row length of the parameter.